K8s ingress and ingress controller ( 404)
I am trying to use K8's ingress controller to setup ingress.
My configuration ->
ingress-nginx-admission-create-w2kpj        0/1     Completed   0             3m35s
ingress-nginx-admission-patch-hpqxx         0/1     Completed   0             3m35s
ingress-nginx-controller-77667b9d9b-mrv5d   1/1     Running     0             3m35s
test                                        1/1     Running     0             3m34s

and my svc
ingress-nginx-controller LoadBalancer   10.210.150.247   10.210.149.47    80:32390/TCP,443:31536/TCP   5m40s

ingress-nginx-controller-admission   ClusterIP      10.210.150.137   <none>           443/TCP                      5m40s

test                                 ClusterIP      10.210.150.168   <none>           9995/TCP                     5m40s

and my ingress
    NAME               CLASS    HOSTS   ADDRESS   PORTS   AGE
    ingress-resource   <none>   *                 80      7m44s

and my ingress.yaml file
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-resource
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: ingress-nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
            service:
                name: test
                port:
                    number: 9995

I am getting 404 when trying ->
10.218.149.47/test
what am i missing ?

As you are configured in the path, your Ingress is set to route traffic from  /  try http://10.218.149.47/  which might work.
